# where is eclipse plugin 's changelog?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

eclipse always notify me update of Groovy-Eclipse Feature,

but i can't find any changelog.

is there any url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for all of the source code that has changed since the previous build?

You can find that at the build server:
http://bamboo.ci.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-V2E36  (for Eclipse 3.6)
http://bamboo.ci.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-V2E37  (for Eclipse 3.7)

Also, you can find the new and noteworthy pages for all releases here:
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin

Comment: Yes, because Eclipse is open source, and has hundreds/thousands of plugins available for it.  Each plugin has a different development team, a different build server, a different code repository, and different development methodologies.  Because of this there is no coherent way of tracking the changes across versions.

Comment: at least,force dp team to fill a field of changelog, when user check  updates,show it, so simple, but so hard...sad..